# WPF binded controlls only update when value changed to null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ironruby

i binded a control to property of the dynamic type, My MainWindow Class inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged, Also defined method OnPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

my xaml looks like that

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}" Name="EquipmentKinds" ItemsSource=" {Binding system_slots}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" SelectionChanged="EquipmentKinds_SelectionChanged"/>
                        <TextBox Name="EditEquipmentKinds" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Height="25" TextChanged="EditEquipmentKinds_TextChanged" />
```

the property system_slots is declared as

```
public dynamic system_slots
    {
        get
        {
            if (_system != null)
            {
                return _system.equipment_kinds;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        set { _system.equipment_kinds = value; OnPropertyChanged("system_slots"); OnPropertyChanged("system"); }
    }
```

Every time i changed system_slots value i called OnPropertyChanged method.

When i e.g. add new slot to system_slots i need to set system_slots to null if i want listbox to update e.g. my code for this is

```
dynamic new_system = CreateCopyOfSystem(system);
        new_system.equipment_kinds.Add("New Slot".ToRubyString());
        system_slots = null;
        system_slots = new_system.equipment_kinds;
        OnPropertyChanged("system");
        OnPropertyChanged("system_slots");
```

If i didn't set system_slots to null it doesn't update, any help since i'm new to WPF??

```
EDIT: What i tried is to use ObservableCollection, DependencyProperties, and I found here an example where someone Get Binding and trigger it manually but still it didn't help.
```

All dynamic types are ruby objects from IronRuby library (means arrays and hashes for collections of custom made classes). If i understand WPF the control should update if is bound to Object and i call OnPropertyChange(Object_name), but it doesn't update until i change Object to null.
Ass For error with observableCollection it was something with Coversion from RubyArray to ObservableCollection.

Comment: It works in small sample I tried. Can you post the code where it is reproducible?

Comment: Strange for me it doesn't work i use VS Express 2010 and Net 4.0

Comment: I don't know about `ToRubyString()`. In sample i tried with simple string values and it works with VS2010 and .Net 4.0.

Comment: `equipment_kinds` is of what type in your actual implementation?

Comment: RubyArray from IronRuby library, toRubyString convert string to MutableString also from IronRuby, the real problem even if i fire OnPropertyChanged in method it doesn't update controls (it for all controls not only one. I also searched for method that allows to trigger control update manually but i didn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `dynamic` it's difficult to tell exactly what types of collection you are using, but there does seem to be one thing you've tripped over.

WPF will only take notice of a `PropertyChanged` event fired for a property if the value of the property has changed.  For reference types, 'changed' means 'not `ReferenceEquals` to the old value'.  You may have appended an item to the list, so it is no longer equal to its old value, but it will still be `ReferenceEquals` to its old value - the list itself has the same address in memory as it did before the item was added to it.

By setting the property to `null` and back to the list, you are actually changing the value of the property, as your collection is not `ReferenceEquals` to `null`.  WPF takes notice of this because the value has changed.  However, if you have a lot of items in the list, this is causing WPF to do unnecessary work, rebuilding the entire listbox every time.

Look at using an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.  This fires events whenever an item is added, removed or changed.  WPF knows about this class (or rather the interface INotifyCollectionChanged that it implements), listens to its events and responds to them.

Comment: I tried using but it's out of question since in dynamic class i use for implementation of ironruby so it's different ruby class which give me errors when i tried to using it

Comment: I don't know IronRuby well enough to comment on how to get ObservableCollections working with it, but in my opinion that is definitely the way to go.  It also wasn't clear at all that your question involved IronRuby.  I've now added an ironruby tag to it.  Finally, what are the errors you mention in your comment?  Edit your question to include what you tried and the errors you got.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - `WPF will only take notice of a PropertyChanged event fired for a property if the value of the property has changed.`. This is not true. Binding engine only hooks for PropertyChanged event. If event is raised explicitly even if value haven't changed, UI still respond to it and refresh corresponding bindings.

Comment: @RohitVats: I think you'll find what I've written **is** true, although I'm struggling to find any documentation to back it up.  If you don't believe me, go fire up Visual Studio, knock up a quick test solution and have a try for yourself.  To be sure, I've just done that myself and can confirm what I've written.  Besides, if what you had written was correct, there would be no question here and the questioner's original code would just work.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - You couldn't find any written documentation because no document exist to validate your false claim. Just create simple TextBlock and bind its Text with some string property via converter. On button click raise property changed event and you will see converter gets hit. (UI asks for it when no actual property change occur). Not sure what makes you claim this, would love to see your sample which makes you think that property needs to be changed.

Comment: Moreover, I have already commented to OP's question that it works in small sample (Issue lies somewhere in his code might be related to Ruby because I validate it with normal objects). Anyhow, assuming your claim to be true but with this line `system_slots = new_system.equipment_kinds;` user is setting it to complete new reference because new_system is completely new object so reference will be different.

Comment: @RohitVats: via a converter?  Do you see the OP using a converter?  If the converter returns a value that isn't `ReferenceEquals` to the last value it returned then a change will be considered to have happened.  I have a test solution [right here](http://www.lack-of.org.uk/stuff/WPFBindingTest.zip). If your claim that WPF responds to every PropertyChanged event is correct, the 'Strings changed' message box should pop up every time you click 'Add an item'.  It does not.

Comment: @RohitVats: if `CreateCopyOfSystem` only creates a shallow copy of the `system` object, then it is perfectly possible that `system_slots` and `new_system.equipment_kinds` are already `ReferenceEquals` to one another before the assignment, which therefore will have no effect.  Of course, I don't know exactly what `CreateCopyOfSystem` does, as I don't have the source to this method.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - Do you see any reference of converter with OP's question in my comment? Converter I mentioned has no relation to OP's question. Since you wrote answer in generic that WPF respond to property change only when value changes doesn't hold valid for all. Even in your sample you use `List<string>` and it needs `CollectionChanged` for same list which I too agree. But not for all objects. Converter method gets hit that means UI respond to property changed event if you are not willing to buy that I won't drag this discussion more.

Comment: `Of course, I don't know exactly what CreateCopyOfSystem does, as I don't have the source to this method.` - So why to make assertions before knowing what it exactly do?